# too many values to unpack python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

am getting this error:-

```
 Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/88f7f9df3fb0504d362e8d32ee79652f.py", line 15, in <module>
    n,q=(int(x) for x in input().split())
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

for this code:-

```
import math
def find_prime(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        k=arr[i]
        count=0
        for j in range(1,int(math.sqrt(k))+1):
            if k%j==0:
                count+=1
        if count>=2:
            arr[i]=0
        else:
            arr[i]=1
t=int(input())
while t!=0:
    n,q=(int(x) for x in input().split())
    arr=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    find_prime(arr)
    for i in range(1,n):
        arr[i]=arr[i]+arr[i-1]
        #print(arr[i],end=" ")
    while q!=0:
        l,r=(int(x) for x in input().split())
        if l>1:
            k=arr[r-1]-arr[l-2]
        else:
            k=arr[r-1]
        q-=1
        print(k)
    t-=1
```

am not getting what is wrong
am giving two inputs only for the corresponding error line.
please help me...
am getting error for multiple test cases.
for a single testcase it is running correctly.

Comment: `(int(x) for x in input().split())` return generator so if you sure that you have two values you just shoul use list `n,q=[int(x) for x in input().split()]`

Comment: I'm curios: what went wrong ?

Comment: I am tempted to replace the while loop by a more pythonic writing, as for example `for _ in range(t):` if the iteration number is not needed inside the loop?

Comment: ohh..thanks.i didn't know,it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`n,q=(int(x) for x in input().split())`

by

`print(list(int(x) for x in input().split()))`

to understand what you are unpacking here.

Comment: it is unpacking the two values that i have given as input,but for multiple testcases it is giving this error.